# Computing column after outer join in Slick

Tags: scala, upgrade, slick, slick-3.0

I'm looking to do something like the following:

```
streetTable.joinLeft(countQuery).on(_.streetId === _._1).map {
    case (_street, _cnt) => (_street.streetId, _cnt.map(_._2).ifNull(0) > 0)
}
```

Where the `countQuery` has two columns, (Int, Int). I want to join left and get a boolean column that is true only if the count is greater than 0, and defaults to false if there was nothing on the `countQuery` side of the join.

I also tried changing `_cnt.map(_._2).ifNull(0) > 0` to `_cnt.map(_._2 > 0).getOrElse(false)`. In both cases, I get this compiler error:

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type slick.ast.TypedType[(slick.lifted.Rep[Int], slick.lifted.Rep[Int])]
```

It may be useful to note that I am in the middle of migrating from Slick 2.1 to 3.1, and my 2.1 code that was working was: `_cnt._2.ifNull(0.asColumnOf[Int]) > 0`

I've been reading through the [Slick 3.0 upgrade guide](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/upgrade.html) and [Slick 3.1 upgrade guide](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/upgrade.html), and I have been migrating most of my code successfully, this is just one of the few snags I have hit.

Comment: Okay I've narrowed it down slightly. I can't even create the Option[Boolean] column with `_cnt.map(_._2 > 0)`. I get the same compilation error.

Comment: I was able to get around the problem by removing the sub-query that counted the number of non-null columns, since we now have the `countDefined` function in Slick 3.1. Since I was then working with only an `Int` column instead of an `Option[Int]` column, I could compute the boolean column from it no problem.